# Obtener datos formulario dinámico creado desde JAVA en Android

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando crear un formulario dinámico en android desde código Java con lo cual no tengo problema, el problema aparece cuando quiero obtener los datos de los campos, no sé como acceder a ellos.

En el siguiente código se ve como tengo un LinearLayout definido en el archivo xml de la interfaz de mi activity, y se le agregan 5 EditText, con lo que no tengo problema. La idea es obtener cada uno de los 5 valores que pueda ingresar en los campos y darles tratamiento.

```
contenedorComponentes = (LinearLayout) findViewById( R.id.contenedorComponentes );

for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{   
    EditText txtComponente  = new EditText( getApplicationContext() );
    contenedorComponentes.addView( txtComponente );
}

Button button= (Button) findViewById( R.id.btnGuardar );
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // En esta parate es donde necesito obtener los datos de los EditText creados previamente, con código Java, pero no sé como hacerlo

    }
});
```

¿debo asignarles un nombre o id a esos campos, como hacerlo y como hacer para obtener el valor de cada uno?

Answer (score 2):

> ¿debo asignarles un nombre o id a esos campos, como hacerlo y como hacer para obtener el valor de cada uno?

Si, yo lo que haría sería dentro del bucle:

```
txtComponente.setId("dato"+i);
```

Y para obtener el valor pues simplemente cogería por id (una vez se haya pulsado el botón) lo puedes hacer con un bucle también mediante:

```
 String btnID = "dato"+i;
 int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(btnID, "id", getPackageName());
 EditText txtObtenido = (EditText) findViewById(resID);
 //aqui pongo un array como ejemplo de donde guardar cada dato del formulario
 arrTxt[i] = txtObtenido.getText();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, tal cual lo que me sugeriste, solo que el id de los objetos deben ser un valor entero ( int ).